# Fit Quadrilateral (Tetragon) to a blob

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, model-fitting

After applying different filtering and segmentation techniques, I end up with an image like this:

[image]

I have access to some contours detection functions that return a list of points on the edge of that object, or returns a fitted polygon (with many edges though, much more than 4).
I want a way to fit a quadrilateral to that shape as I know it is a front face of a shoebox that is supposed to be a quadrilateral. Due to the perspective view, the parallelity is not conserved so I have no constraints for now and just need four line segments encompassing this box.

What I could find until now was only rectangle fitting, which doesn't really returns the result I need as it forces the fitted quadrilateral to be rectangular.

If I had access to the relative angle of the camera to that shoebox and knew the distance of the shoebox from my camera, I could generate a Homography matrix and warp the image such that the shoebox appears rectangular again, but for now I have no access to such information and want to do it based purely vision.

Any known approaches for solving such a problem?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Update**: [Dev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138000/fit-quadrilateral-tetragon-to-a-blob/74620309#74620309) is great and deserves more votes.
It's great because it includes a Python implmentation of a paper that **dynamically** computes the 4 points.

My answer is useful a first principles approach:

- great when getting started from scratch and trying/experimenting different approaches
- not a robust solution since it relies on working out threshold values on a case by case basis (e.g. contour simplification epsilon value, etc.).

If it's still useful to understand these base principles read along.

I recommend the following steps:

1. `threshold()` the image
2. [`dilate()` the image](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application-development/9781785283932/2/ch02lvl1sec24/erosion-and-dilation) - this will remove the black line splitting the top and bottom section and also darker artifacts on the lower part
3. [`findContours()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) using setting to retrieve only external contours(`RETR_EXTERNAL`) and simplify the output(`CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`)
4. process the contours further

**Step 1:threshold**

```
# threshold image
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
cv2.imshow('threshold ',thresh)
```

[image: threshold]

**Step 2:dilate**

```
# dilate thresholded image - merges top/bottom 
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=3)
cv2.imshow('threshold dilated',dilated)
```

[image: dilate]

**Step 3: find contours**

```
# find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, 0, (255,255,255), 3)
print "contours:",len(contours)
print "largest contour has ",len(contours[0]),"points"
```

[image: contours]

Notice that dilating first, then using simple external contours gets you shape you're after, but it's still pretty complex (containg 279 points)

From this point onward you can futher [process the contour features](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html).
There are a few options, available such as:

**a: getting the min. area rectangle**

```
# minAreaRect
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[0])
box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(255,255,255),3)
```

[image: minAreaRect]

Can be useful, but not exactly what you need.

**b: convex hull**

```
# convexHull
hull = cv2.convexHull(contours[0])
cv2.drawContours(img, [hull], 0, (255,255,255), 3)
print "convex hull has ",len(hull),"points"
```

[image: convexHull]

Better, but you still have 22 points to deal with and it's not tight as it could be

**c: simplify contours**

```
# simplify contours

epsilon = 0.1*cv2.arcLength(contours[0],True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[0],epsilon,True)
cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], 0, (255,255,255), 3)
print "simplified contour has",len(approx),"points"
```

[image: aproxPolyDP]

This is probably what you're after: just 4 points.
You can play with the epsilon value if you need more points.

Bare in mind, now you have a quad, but the picture is flattened: there's no information on perspective/3d rotation.

Full OpenCV Python code listing (comment/uncomment as needed, use the reference to adapt to c++/java/etc.):

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('XwzWQ.png',0)

# threshold image
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
cv2.imshow('threshold ',thresh)

# dilate thresholded image - merges top/bottom 
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=3)
cv2.imshow('threshold dilated',dilated)

# find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# cv2.drawContours(img, contours, 0, (255,255,255), 3)
print "contours:",len(contours)
print "largest contour has ",len(contours[0]),"points"

# minAreaRect
# rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[0])
# box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)
# box = np.int0(box)
# cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(255,255,255),3)

# convexHull
# hull = cv2.convexHull(contours[0])
# cv2.drawContours(img, [hull], 0, (255,255,255), 3)
# print "convex hull has ",len(hull),"points"

# simplify contours
epsilon = 0.1*cv2.arcLength(contours[0],True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[0],epsilon,True)
cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], 0, (255,255,255), 3)
print "simplified contour has",len(approx),"points"


# display output 
cv2.imshow('image',img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This is a GREAT answer! Thank YOU very much! That's what i was looking for!

Comment: This is an outstanding answer.  Thanks

Comment: FYI, this is not guaranteed to have all original contour points inside of the quadrilateral.  Sometimes DP shaves a little off.  If you need to include all original points, then use the algorithm in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74620309/848419

Answer (score 7):

A more accurate way to fit quadrangles to arbitrary masks is to use the technique from [View Frustum Optimization
To Maximize Object’s Image Area](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=1fbd43f3827fffeb76641a9c5ab5b625eb5a75ba).

---

Here's the output -

[image]

---

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sympy


def appx_best_fit_ngon(mask_cv2, n: int = 4) -> list[(int, int)]:
    # convex hull of the input mask
    mask_cv2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(mask_cv2, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(
        mask_cv2_gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
    )
    hull = cv2.convexHull(contours[0])
    hull = np.array(hull).reshape((len(hull), 2))

    # to sympy land
    hull = [sympy.Point(*pt) for pt in hull]

    # run until we cut down to n vertices
    while len(hull) > n:
        best_candidate = None

        # for all edges in hull ( <edge_idx_1>, <edge_idx_2> ) ->
        for edge_idx_1 in range(len(hull)):
            edge_idx_2 = (edge_idx_1 + 1) % len(hull)

            adj_idx_1 = (edge_idx_1 - 1) % len(hull)
            adj_idx_2 = (edge_idx_1 + 2) % len(hull)

            edge_pt_1 = sympy.Point(*hull[edge_idx_1])
            edge_pt_2 = sympy.Point(*hull[edge_idx_2])
            adj_pt_1 = sympy.Point(*hull[adj_idx_1])
            adj_pt_2 = sympy.Point(*hull[adj_idx_2])

            subpoly = sympy.Polygon(adj_pt_1, edge_pt_1, edge_pt_2, adj_pt_2)
            angle1 = subpoly.angles[edge_pt_1]
            angle2 = subpoly.angles[edge_pt_2]

            # we need to first make sure that the sum of the interior angles the edge
            # makes with the two adjacent edges is more than 180°
            if sympy.N(angle1 + angle2) <= sympy.pi:
                continue

            # find the new vertex if we delete this edge
            adj_edge_1 = sympy.Line(adj_pt_1, edge_pt_1)
            adj_edge_2 = sympy.Line(edge_pt_2, adj_pt_2)
            intersect = adj_edge_1.intersection(adj_edge_2)[0]

            # the area of the triangle we'll be adding
            area = sympy.N(sympy.Triangle(edge_pt_1, intersect, edge_pt_2).area)
            # should be the lowest
            if best_candidate and best_candidate[1] < area:
                continue

            # delete the edge and add the intersection of adjacent edges to the hull
            better_hull = list(hull)
            better_hull[edge_idx_1] = intersect
            del better_hull[edge_idx_2]
            best_candidate = (better_hull, area)

        if not best_candidate:
            raise ValueError("Could not find the best fit n-gon!")

        hull = best_candidate[0]

    # back to python land
    hull = [(int(x), int(y)) for x, y in hull]

    return hull
```

Here's the code I used to generate this image -

```py
hull = appx_best_fit_ngon(mask_cv2)

for idx in range(len(hull)):
    next_idx = (idx + 1) % len(hull)
    cv2.line(mask_cv2, hull[idx], hull[next_idx], (0, 255, 0), 1)

for pt in hull:
    cv2.circle(mask_cv2, pt, 2, (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

Comment: This is great! One improvement that works way better for me is always removing the shortest edge (where distance between `edge_pt_1` and `edge_pt_2` is smallest) instead of picking the smallest area of the new triangle.