# How to find a four point polygon approximation with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, perspectivecamera

So I have a problem that requires me to get a perspective transform on a series of numbers. However, in order to get the four point transform, I need the correct points to send as parameters to the function. I couldn't find any methods that will solve this problem, and I've tried convex hull (returns more than four), minAreaRect (it returns a rectangle).
[image: This is the image I've been working with]

Comment: You can try use Radon transform.  It will be necessary to find two angles at which the difference between the maximum and minimum projection values is minimal.

Comment: I couldn't understand the question relationship with the optical-character-recognition (`ocr`)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience with OCR, but I would hope all the text segments live on the same perspective plane.

If so, how about using a simplified convex Hull (e.g. `convexHull()` then [`approxPolyDP`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#contour-approximation)) on one of seven connected components to get the points / compute perspective, then apply the same unwarp to an a scaled quad that encloses all the components ? (probably not perfect, but close)

Hopefully the snippets in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138000/fit-quadrilateral-tetragon-to-a-blob/41143028#41143028) will help:
[image: 4 point poly around the image of an envelope]

I really hope the same perspective transformation can be applied to each yellow text connected component.